# If $v_1, ..., v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of $V$, then we can make a list $w_1, ..., w_m$ s.t no $T$ satisfies $Tv_k=w_k$ for each $k=1, ..., m$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Suppose $v_1,..., v_m$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in $V$.
> Suppose also that $W \neq \{ 0 \}$. Prove that there exist $w_1,...,w_m
> \in W$ such that no $T \in L(V,W)$ satisfies $Tv_k= w_k$ for each
> $k=1,...,m$.

I'm struggling to fix something in my proof.

Here's my proof.

Proof begins.

Since the list is linearly dependent, $\exists v_i=\sum_{j \neq i}^{}c_jv_j$.

Let a set of all $v_i$'s be $A$. Suppose there are $n$ elements in $A$.

Remove them from the list $v_1,...,v_m$.

Then, there left a linearly independent list. Rename each vector as $u_1,...,u_{m-n}$

We extend it to the basis of $V$. $u_1, ..., u_{m-n}, u_{m-n+1}, ...,u_m$

Then, make a list of ($m-1$)-many $0 \in W$ and one non-zero vectors.
Rename them as $w_1,...,w_m$ where $w_l \neq 0$ s.t $l \in \{ i: v_i \in A \}$.

Then there exists a unique $T \in L(V,W)$ s.t $Tu_k=w_k$ for each $k \in \{ 1,...,m \}$.

Consider $Tv_l$.

$Tv_l=T \left (\sum_{j \neq l}^{}c_ju_j  \right )=\sum_{j \neq l}^{}c_jw_j=0 \neq w_l$.

And, since $T$ is a unique linear map, we conclude no linear map satisfies $Tv_a=w_a$ for each $a \in \{ 1,...,m \}$.

End of Proof.

If this is valid proof, I want to use a better word instead of "since $T$ is a unique linear map," but can't think of any.

Can I get any suggestions?

Comment: you need to prove it for all $T\in L(V,W)$, not just the $T$ that you chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $ v_1 = \sum_{i>1} c_i v_i$. Pick $w_i$ such that $ w_1 \neq \sum_{i>1} c_i w_i$.

Show that this choice satisfies the conditions.